# No packets showing up in Wireshark despite Client-Server communication

Tags: wireshark, loopback

I am somewhat new to computer networking and I created a little project where I have two computers connected to an Ethernet switch, forming a small network. Computer `server` (`192.168.1.1`) has a mail-server program installed on it (*communigate server*) and the other computer `client` (`192.168.1.2`) tries to access mails via an https interface. (I verified both PCs can ping each other).

On `client`, I am logging in and out of the web interface while recording traffic on both PCs via wireshark.

What I noticed is that `server` does not seem to receive any packets at all from `client`. (No packets from `192.168.1.2`)

On the `client` machine, I do find lots of TCP packets, but they all have the address `127.0.0.1` (both as source and destination) and there are no packets from `192.168.1.1`

When I repeat this experiment with the `server` ethernet cable disconnected, `client` is unable to access the web-interface, so I assume there should be some sort of connection between the two?

Does anyone understand why WireShark does not record any packets from `client` to `server`?

Comment: Check the Wireshark filters - if client and server are communicating, there must be traffic on the wire. Is the client maybe connected wirelessly in parallel?

Comment: Make sure you are capturing data on the correct interface on the PC. You may be capturing on the loopback or other virtual interface instead of the Ethernet interface.

Comment: So it turned out that I indeed captured the traffic on the Loopback Adapter... Thank you very much for helping!

Comment: You should write your own answer to the question, so others can benefit from your experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turned out that I simply chose the incorrect network adapter in Wireshark as shown in the picture below:

[image]